# Is it suggestable to use generics for large amount of data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, datareader

I'm having let's say thousands of `Customer` records and I have to show them on a webform. Also, I have one `CustomerEntity` which has 10 properties. So when I fetch data in using a `DataReader` and convert it into `List<CustomerEntity>` I am required to loop through the data two times.

So is the use of generics suggestable in such a scenario? If yes then what will be my applications performance?

For E.g.

In CustomerEntity class, i'm having CustomerId & CustomerName propeties. And i'm getting 100 records from Customer Table 
Then for Preparing List i've wrote following code

```
while (dr.Read()) 
    { 
       // creation of new object of customerEntity 
       // code for getting properties of CustomerEntity 
       for (var index = 0; index <  MyProperties.Count; index++) 
       { 
         MyProperty.setValue(CustEntityObject,dr.GetValue(index)); 
        } 
      //adding CustEntity object to List<CustomerEntity> 
    }
```

How can i avoid these two loops. Is their any other mechanism?

Comment: updated my answer to reflect the extra info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not really sure how generics ties into data-volume; they are unrelated concepts... it also isn't clear to me *why* this requires you to read everything twice. But yes: generics are fine when used in volume (why wouldn't they be?). But of course, the best way to find a problem is profiling (either server performance or bandwidth - perhaps more the latter in this case).

Of course the better approach is: don't show thousands of records on a web form; what is the user going to do with that? Use paging, searching, filtering, ajax, etc - every trick imaginable - but don't send thousands of records to the client.

---

Re the updated question; the loop for setting properties isn't necessarily bad. This is an entirely appropriate inner loop. Before doing anything, profile to see if this is *actually* a problem. I suspect that sheer bandwidth (between server and client, or server and database) is the biggest issue. If you can prove that **this loop** is a problem there are things you can do do optimise:

- switch to using `PropertyDescriptor` (rather than `PropertyInfo`), and use [`HyperDescriptor`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx) to make it a lot faster
- write code with `DynamicMethod` to do the job - requires some understanding of IL, but very fast
- write a .NET 3.5 / LINQ `Expression` to do the same and use `.Compile()` - like the second point, but (IMO) a bit easier

I can add examples for the first and third bullets; I don't *really* want to write an example for the second, simply because I wouldn't write that code *myself* that way any more (I'd use the 3rd option where available, else the 1st).

Comment: +1. I remember a client requirement that wanted to show all records returned from searches...until it was pointed out "what are end usesr going to do with several million rows!! (never mind the load on server)"

Comment: In Datareader, I required to loop through twice because one loop is for actual records & another inner for no of properties. This looping is for setting datareader's value to List<CustomerEntity>.
Second point is acceptible, I can lesser down the records but how can i avoid looping ?
Thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult what to say the performance will be, but consider these things -

1. Generics provides type saftey
2. If you're going to display 10,000 records in the page, your application will probably be unusable. If records are being paged, consider returning only those records that are actually needed for the page you are on.
3. You shouldn't need to loop through the data twice. What are you doing with the data?